# Inserting a background-image from asset pipeline with tailwind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, tailwind-css

I've been trying to add a background picture with the help of Tailwind in my project but it won't work, I'm guessing because of an asset-pipeline conflict somewhere ?

What I've tried:

- Inserting the image directly in my `tailwind.config` like so:
  `'essential-oil': "url('/assets/images/essential-oil.png')"`, `'essential-oil': "asset-url('essential-oil.png')"`
- Inserting the image directly in my HTML with a `style: "background-image:url(/assets/images/essential-oil.png)`
- Putting my image in an other place in the app like `Public`

None of the solutions work. At worse, all of my style disappear from my HTML at best, the style looks ok but the picture is not there.
Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: In rails scss you are allowed to use image-url() instead of url. This maps the correct file after compiling the assets.
I am not sure if your tailwind production build process is included in your asset pipeline. If not, you have to put the image inside your public folder.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

1. Move the image under the asset pipeline directory `app/assets`.
2. Refer to the new asset in tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                'essential-oil': "url('essential-oil.png')"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Refer to the background image in the HTML

```html
  <div class="bg-essential-oil">
  </div>
```

#### Details

This works since Sprockets has been changed to support fingerprinting plain `url([asset-path])` references. See https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/476. Make sure you're on Sprockets 3.3.0 or higher. I got the answer after I opened an issue on the `tailwindcss-rails` repository: https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/137#issuecomment-1025853968.

By extension, it also works by putting the URL inline:

```html
<div class="bg-[url('essential-oil.png')]">Has the essential oil background</div>
```

#### Reference

[Rails Guide - The asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Move image into the public folder
2. Refer to image in the `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {

  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
       'hero-pattern': "url('/assets/icon-arrows-left.svg')",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you miss out on the fingerprinting and processing the asset pipeline does.

Answer (score 0):

put single quotes are your image path style: "background-image:url('/assets/images/essential-oil.png')

see https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/129